# Debian iptables, netstate. DDOS?

Tags: debian, iptables, ddos, netstat

My server has been timing out and crashing lately.

I ran this command:

> netstat -anp |grep 'tcp\|udp' | awk '{print $5}' | cut -d: -f1 | sort | uniq -c | sort -n

Check the picture for result. Does the two IPs in the end ddos me?
And how do I block them with IPtables?[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Given the astoundingly large number of connections, it's possible that the host `75.67.41.234` and maybe `71.232.145.129` may be DoSing you with a SYN flood (or they may just be scraping your website with an extremely ineffective bot or something).  A sample of the traffic could confirm this.

To protect against this type of DDoS (and not against a flood, which you cannot protect against with local rules and need your ISP's help to deal with), you can set up firewall rules with iptables to limit the number of connections a single host can open to you at once.  This is an example of such a rule:

```
iptables -t filter -A INPUT -i $WAN_IF -p tcp -syn -m connlimit --connlimit-above 10 -j DROP
```

You can use a different target (`-j REJECT` for instance) to perform different actions, and you can set a different connection  limit than 10.